# Can't install Visual Studio Community Edition 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I can't install the Community Edition 2013 of Visual Studio. I always get the following error message:

```
Visual Studio Professional 2013 is currently installed on this machine. 
Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2013 and retry.
```

The problem here is that I never installed Visual Studio Professional 2013. I installed Visual Studio Express 2013 and I uninstalled it because it didn't want to start up.
So why is it telling me such nonsense? Even when I search for Visual Studio I can't find anything on my computer.

How can I install the Community Edition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check registry for this key "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\12.0\professional". If present remove it.
Then install Community Edition.

Answer (score 6):

Also check registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\12.0

Comment: I also searched for many hours. Deleting the key above finally solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or when in doubt, delete everything! I found that deleting the DevDiv folder in the registry fixed the solution.

Comment: @BehzadKhosravifar Doesn't look like a new question to me.